# Does YugabyteDB automatically handle partition(or tablet) skew?

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

In a situation where I know that hash would skew data.
Imagine a messenger app (which actually is my case), It has a few large chat groups with around 100,000 members and other chats are under 1000 members. If I put `chatid` as partition key for storing messages, it would cause partition skew since a large group would generate more messages.
Does YugabyteDB support auto-splitting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For storing data in a table with a primary key, we use HASH as the default index type and store the data that way. This enforces unique values, and the different values are distributed over the shards via hashing.

If you don't use `chatid` as a primary key, and store a large number of identical values, which is a higher number than the others, then that will be a higher number than the others. If you choose that as the partitioning key, this will take the same division and thus will not be even.

Yes, this would skew the tablet sizes in HASH sharding. But a tablet/partition can grow up to ~15GB before it starts becoming a bottleneck. If you don’t expect a chat-room to have more than 15GB of data, then you should be fine even with HASH sharding.

If you want to use RANGE sharding, then you have to make sure that `chatid` is not a sequence or auto incrementing number, because that would result in all new chat-rooms ending up in 1 tablet, thus becoming a hotspot.

Auto splitting is available in master but not yet ready for production use: https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/architecture/docdb-sharding/tablet-splitting/